# Numpy Sum from a multidimensional array?

Tags: python, numpy, sum

If I had data such as:

```
data = [[3, 2014], [4, 2014], [6, 2013], [6,2013]] etc...
```

What is the best way to calculate the sum by year in python?

Comment: Is `data` a list of lists or a NumPy array?

Comment: The data is a list of lists. But I would think the easiest way is to convert to NumPy array?

Comment: Are you wedded to using `numpy`?  This is a simple `groupby` operation, and while you can do that in `numpy` it would take less time to do it in `pandas` than it took to write this sentence.

Comment: A numpy array would be easy IF the all the years had the same number of entries, and they occurred in a regular pattern.  Then you could slice and reshape to produce an array with one year per row.  But it things are irregular, a default dictionary or groupby approach is better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a dict if you need both the year and sum:

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = [[3, 2014], [4, 2014], [6, 2013], [6,2013]]
d = defaultdict(int)

for v, k in data:
    d[k] += v
print(d)
```

Prints:

```
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {2013: 12, 2014: 7})
```

Comment: Thanks!! What about using NumPy would it be easier?

Comment: @Ben, not sure it would be easier, if you want to be able to access which year is associated with which sum then a dict seems pretty much exactly what you want. another option would be pandas but I really think a dict is what you want.

Comment: all solutions work fine but I just want to point out one thing. sometimes the simplest solution is the fastest. I'm sure speed is not an issue here but I did a quick timeit on my machine for this solution, @Marcus's and my own: for 100, 000 iterations, this one: 0.88s, Marcus: 6.9s, mine: 0.21s

Comment: @JulienSpronck,  a defaultdict will be more efficient once you test it on something containing more than 4 elements. Try `data = [choice(random.data) for _ in range(10000)]`

Comment: @JulienSpronck, that should be `random.choice(data)`!

Answer (score 1):

There's a specific python standard library class for that, `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter
from operator import add

counters = [Counter({row[1]:row[0]}) for row in data]
result = reduce(add, counters)
```

your result is a dict-behaving object:

```
{2013: 12, 2014: 7}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand the question. Here might be a simple answer without added modules.

```
dic = {}

for dat, year in data:
    if year not in dic:
        dic[year] = dat
    else:
        dic[year] += dat
```

or if you prefer

```
dic = {}
for dat, year in data:
    dic[year] = dat if year not in dic else dic[year] + dat
```

Answer (score 1):

As reported by DSM, using pandas and grouby it seems easy:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [[3, 2014], [4, 2014], [6, 2013], [6,2013]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['value', 'year'])
df.groupby(['year']).sum()
```

which returns:

```
      value
year       
2013     12
2014      7
```

It nice because you can easy get more information like  mean, median, std etc..

```
df.groupby(['year']).mean()
df.groupby(['year']).median() 
df.groupby(['year']).std()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`counter()`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and `+=`.

```
import collections
data = [[3, 2014], [4, 2014], [6, 2013], [6,2013]]

c = collections.Counter()

for i, j in data:
    c += collections.Counter({j: i})

print(c)
```

---

> A Counter is a dict subclass for counting hashable objects. It is an
>   unordered collection where elements are stored as dictionary keys and
>   their counts are stored as dictionary values.

You can add Counters, for example:

```
a = collections.Counter(a=1, b=2)
b = collections.Counter(a=3, c=3)    
print(a+b)
```

prints `Counter({'a': 4, 'c': 3, 'b': 2})`.